# Add a shortcut to Startup folder with parameters in Adobe AIR

Tags: air, adobe

I am trying to include a link to my application in the Startup folder with a parameter passed to the program.

I think it would work if I created the shortcut locally and then added it to my source. After that I could copy it to the Startup folder on first run.

```
File.userDirectory.resolvePath("Start Menu\\Programs\\Startup\\startup.lnk");
```

However, I am trying to get this to occur during install. I see there is are some settings related to the installation in app.xml, but nothing that lets me install it to two folders, or use a parameter.

```
<!-- The subpath of the standard default installation location to use. Optional. -->
<!-- <installFolder></installFolder> -->

<!-- The subpath of the Windows Start/Programs menu to use. Optional. -->
<!-- <programMenuFolder></programMenuFolder> -->
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to Air, but also haven't found any way to customize the install process.  It looks like you're limited to your application code.  (Updating appears more flexible.)

From your example, it looks like you want your app' to run with a parameter constant each time Windows starts.  So you're probably already aware you can set:

```
NativeApplication.nativeApplication.startAtLogin=true
```

when your app' first runs.  Could you combine this with your parameter in a settings file in the application or user directory and accomplish what you need?